# Problem with comparing single character with character in string by a loop c++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to learn c++ and one of the assignments is to ask the user for a letter - then ask for a string of text and count how many times the 1st letter is repeated in the string of text.

I have written some code that successfully gets to the point of asking for the letter & the string of text - I can display both

I can traverse the string of text counting how many letters there are in the string.  When I try to add an if check to  compare the current letter in the string inside the loop with the letter 1st asked for - I get this compile error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] 
if (textToCount[i] == letterToCount)
```

this is the full code I have written

```
char getLetterToCount(char letterToCount[]);
char getTextToCount(char textToCount[]);
int countLetters(char letterToCount[], char textToCount[]);

int main()
{
   char letterToCount[1];
   getLetterToCount(letterToCount);
   char textToCount[256];
   cin.ignore();
   getTextToCount(textToCount);
   countLetters(letterToCount, textToCount);
   return 0;
}

char getLetterToCount(char letterToCount[])
{
   cout <<  "Enter a letter: ";
   cin >>  letterToCount;
}

char getTextToCount(char textToCount[])
{
   cout <<  "Enter text: ";
   cin.getline(textToCount, 256);
}

int countLetters(char letterToCount[], char textToCount[])
{
   int numChrsInString = 0;
   int numTimesChrtoCountrepeated = 0;
   for (int i = 0; textToCount[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      if (textToCount[i] == letterToCount)
      {
         numTimesChrtoCountrepeated++;
      }
   }
   cout << "num chrs in string: "
        << numChrsInString
        << "num times chr counted: "
        << numTimesChrtoCountrepeated
        << endl;
}
```

I did a fair bit of output to try and figure out what was wrong with these - I pulled the code for that out because it made it a bit more confusing.

BUT the compile error explains what is wrong, I just don't understand why it is wrong because the things I am trying to compare are BOTH text letters...

It would be great if someone who knows c++ can explain what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a `char` with a pointer to `char`
Use:

```
if (textToCount[i] == letterToCount[0])
                                   ~~~
```

<sup>*Note: There are few obvious nitpicking but above is the main compiler error cause*</sup>

Comment: Brilliant thank you! this solved it   much appreciated. I'm sure there are also other aspects of the code where my style and syntax could be better - I'm still very much a newbie in c++.  Thank you for the help - and the pointers... [no pun intended... ;-) ]

Answer (score 1):

In C++, arrays are pointers. C++ considers `lettertocount` to be a pointer because you're passing it as an array. You don't want to pass that; you want to pass just a character:

```
int countLetters(char letterToCount, char textToCount[])
```

A bigger question to my mind is, why do you think you have to pass `lettertocount` as an array? Apparently it's just one letter. When you invoke this function do you eventually want to count multiple letters?

Comment: Hmmm...  Probably the best response I can give is that I am not fully understanding what I am doing just yet.  I will have a go at taking on board your feedback to improve this actual code.  I think my thought process was that I *needed* to pass it as a parameter...  BUT like I say - I will try to figure out what I was doing wrong based on this feedback.

Comment: You _do_ need to pass `letterToCount` as a parameter, but based on your description of the problem, it only needs to be a `char`, not a `char []`.